# wget - corrupted directories

Tags: php, wget

I am using wget to create an HTML mirror of a php templated site on localhost. I am encountering a problem with some directories being mirrored as extensionless documents.

What could be causing this problem?

I am using this command:

```
$ wget -mk http://www.example.com/
```

[image: A screenshot of corrupted directories.]

Comment: Is there some significance to the spelling `wGet` rather than `wget`?

Comment: I've seen it written that way in some docs. Is that incorrect? Changed it, since official docs don't capitalize.

Comment: what's the URL that leads to `becoming-rental-pro`? `http://localhost/becoming-rental-pro` or `http://localhost/becoming-rental-pro.html`?

Comment: The command name is `wget`, and Unix command names are case-sensitive. I've seen documentation refer to it as `Wget`, but I've never seen it referred to as `wGet`.

Comment: @awk_FTW `http://localhost/becoming-rental-pro`

Comment: @itsjustluck then wget is doing exactly what you told it to do. The names of the files are derived from the URL unless you instruct it to do something different.

Comment: @awk_FTW It's supposed to be a directory. 'Success' is correctly mirrored as a directory.

Comment: So what is the actual content of, e.g. `getting_started`?

Answer (score 2):

> What could be causing this problem?

Have you checked that the actual site always returns documents with an extension?  There is no protocol which requires this and it is completely normal to not use them; the document type is determined by the http headers and not any suffix on the address. Of course, your file browser *does* use file extensions to identify documents, so this may be an annoyance.

For example, this page is literally  `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124741/wget-corrupted-directories`, and if you fetch it with `wget`, it will produce a file `wget-corrupted-directories` with no extension, which contains html data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I mean to create directories, not files. To my knowledge directories have no extensions.

Comment: This page is not a directory, right?  But do you see an `.html` extension in the browser nav bar?  No, because there is no extension associated with the address.  It is still an html page, and this is indicated in the http headers sent by the server.  **Your browser does not use or care about filename extensions**, so they are considered superfluous in delivering content.  If I download this page with `wget`, I get a file with no extension.  If I download it with `wget --html-extension`, I get *the exact same file* and wget adds a `.html` because the http headers indicate this.

Comment: Put another way: *Do not confuse URLs with file paths.*  URLs are **not** file paths or file names, and don't expect them to work like such.  They may (or may not) correspond to static files stored on the server, but that is just happenstance.  There does not need to be any such relation, and if there is, the names do not have to be in any way the same, because again, **[a URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)** is not a file name (that wikipedia page linked is another example -- an html page, but the URL does not end with '.html').

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `--html-extension` flag.

I would suggest using this syntax instead:

```
wget \
 --recursive \
 --no-clobber \
 --page-requisites \
 --html-extension \
 --convert-links \
 --restrict-file-names=windows \
 --domains website.org \
 --no-parent \
     www.website.org
```

Comment: `--html-extension` produces the same result.

Comment: Also this answer only produces the root index file.

Comment: @itsjustluck you'll need to add `-m` or `--mirror`